# Creating a string array in jsfl for flash cs6

Tags: flash, flash-cs6, jsfl

I have a simple problem while creating array.Below is the example.

```
var names:Array = new Array(); 
trace(names.length); // output: 0
```

While running the code I am getting the following error

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

Plz guide me.I am running this code in Flash cs6

Comment: Are you sure you want to work with JSFL file format? Because JSFL files are used only for creating tools purposses (e.g. automatization of common tasks). Also, the code above would throw some exceptions in JSFL: as I know there are no type declaration in JSFL and, also, there is no method trace (instead, you should use fl.trace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like a regular AS3 code, but JSFL has its own features, which are different from AS3. Here an example of the same code, but for JSFL:

```
var names = []; 
fl.trace(names.length);
```

Comment: Thank you Mark Dolbyrev.